# Executing a shell script that requires sudo from a web app

Tags: java, shell, sudo, elevated-privileges

Given that the web application doesn't have su privileges, I'd like to execute a shell script that requires sudo. I'd also like to avoid having the user input the password. What are my options? This is basically what I'm trying to do.

### Wicket Application (Form for changing the IP)

```
@Override
protected void onSubmit() {
    System.out.println("Submitted");            
    try {
        Shell.updateIp("eth0", "192.168.217.129");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

### Shell.java

```
public static void updateIp(String ethernetInterface, String ip) throws IOException {
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("/home/keeboi/Desktop/iptool.sh", ethernetInterface, ip);
    Process child = builder.start();
    Network.readOutput(child);
    child.destroy();
}
```

iptool.sh executes a runnable jar.

### iptool.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo java -jar changeip.jar $1 $2
```

And I'm getting:

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
Sorry, try again.
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
Sorry, try again.
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
Sorry, try again.
sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts
```

Again, I'd like to emphasize that the web app isn't given any su privileges and I'd like to avoid asking the user for password.

**Edit:**

I've already tried adding `keeboi ALL = NOPASSWD: /home/keeboi/Desktop/iptool.sh` to my `/etc/sudoers` but it still requires a password.

**Update**

Added `keeboi ALL = NOPASSWD: /home/keeboi/Desktop/changeip.jar` too, no dice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just add `NOPASSWD` in /etc/sudoers:

```
user     ALL = NOPASSWD: /home/keeboi/Desktop/iptool.sh
```

That switches password check off.

Comment: No, that is not important; but you've made another mistake: you must add `java`, not .jar file to the `sudoers`. Or better create a shell script that contains `java ...` line and add the script.

Comment: I'd like to clarify though: how I solved it was adding `keeboi ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/java` to my `/etc/sudoers`. My `iptool.sh` which contains the java command is already added to sudoers, why do I need to add `/usr/bin/java`?

Comment: @BroKevinD.: No, that's not right. You needn't to add `/usr/bin/java`, it is enough to add just a script that you want to run. When you have added the script, you can run it using `sudo`.

Comment: hmm... not currently in my dev machine, so I'll check it out tomorrow. Wrong path to the script probably.